# Como mudar a cor do curso do meu SearchView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml

Por enquanto ele está branco e eu preciso colocar ele na cor preta, achei varias tutorias, porem não achei um que funcione, como faço isso?

Código:

```
    searchViewPesquisa = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchViewPesquisa);

    EditText searchEditText = (EditText) searchViewPesquisa.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
    searchEditText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textColorThird));
    searchEditText.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textColorThird));

    searchViewPesquisa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            searchViewPesquisa.setIconified(false);
        }
    });
```

xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorBackgroud">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchViewPesquisa"
        style="@style/SearchViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

style:

```
<style name="SearchViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">

    <item name="searchHintIcon">@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp</item>
    <item name="closeIcon">@drawable/ic_close</item>
    <item name="searchIcon">@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

Eu resolvi criando um cursor "cursor_color300.xml" na pasta drawable assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois eu defini ele na propriedade textCursorDrawable no meu tema principal assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se tudo estiver correto irá funcionar perfeitamente.

Comment: Não use fotos para manifestar código. A visualização pode se tornar mum prolema dependendo do dispositivo usado pela leitor. Também não é possível usar [CTRL + C] [CTRL + V] em imagem de código. O ideal é texto formatado co Markdown.